# Eyefinity across 2 Radeon R9 270 cards using mini display port

Tags: multiple-monitors, crossfire, eyefinity, dual-gpu

I have 2 R9 270 cards, each 1 has one Apple cinema display connected via the display port. I'd like to use Eyefinity to create a display group so my system treats them both as one giant monitor. Eyefinity doesn't seem to like that I'm going across 2 cards because when I attempt to set up the group it throws the following error:

> There are not enough displays for AMD Eyefinity. If you are using
>   more than one display, make sure that your displays are properly
>   connected.

I tried connecting another monitor via the DVI port on one of the cards. Wouldn't you know that monitor and the monitor also connected to that card are able to be grouped as a display group in the Eyefinity settings. But I still can't seem to get the 2 main monitors to be recognized in the Eyefinity config.

A few other things to note:

- The Apple monitors are both using display port to mini display port adapters
- Crossfire is currently disabled